# Proof of Chebyshev's inequality question

Tags: probability-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Proof_assuming_random_variable_X_is_continuous

In this proof of the Chebyshev's inequality, why is it assumed that $f_{X-E(X)}=f_{(X-E(X))^2}$, where$f$ is the probability density function?

The second line in this proof says:

$$
\operatorname {Var} (X)=\sigma ^{2}=\int _{\mathbb {R} }(x-\mu )^{2}f(x)\,dx,
$$

shouldn't the p.d.f. be $f_{(X-E(X))^2}(x)$ instead of $f(x)$? In the proof later, they use:

$$
\Pr(|X-\mu |\geq k\sigma )=\int _{|x-\mu |\geq k\sigma }f(x)\ dx,
$$
which means that their $f(x)$ equals by definition to $f_{X-E(X)}(x)$. So, again, why is it assumed that $f_{X-E(X)}=f_{(X-E(X))^2}$?

Comment: The Wikipedia proof never mentions "$f_{X-E(X)}(x)$" or any such monstrosities...

Comment: @lord-shark-the-unknown 

yes but they write down p.d functions of both random variables $X-E(X)$ and $(X-E(X)^2$ under the same name $f$ and i dont understand how they use them interchangeably edit: $f$ and not $f(X)$, sorry

Comment: $f(x)$ is the PDF of $X$. The line $Var(X)$ is how the variance of the r.v. $X$ is $defined$, the $f$ inside that integral is still the PDF of $X$. Perhaps you should review the definitions of PDF and variance to clear up your confusion, or add more content to your question to guide the answers to more specific grounds.

Comment: @FedePoncio from WIkipedia: "If ${\displaystyle X}$ is a random variable whose cumulative distribution function admits a density ${\displaystyle f(x)}$, then the expected value is defined as the following Lebesgue integral, if the integral exists:

${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} [X]=\int _{\mathbb {R} }xf(x)\,dx.}$"

So, for r.v. $X-E(X)$ there should be a different PDF?

Comment: @FedePoncio im really sorry, couldn't edit right away, check my comment now :/

Comment: In your notation, $$E[\phi(x)]=\int_{\Bbb R}\phi(x)f(x)\,dx$$ for any reasonable function $\phi$.